# Java- How to fix my exception in spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, console

```
 import java.awt.List;
   import java.util.Properties;

   public class CollectionExample {

    private List examplelist;

    private Properties exampleprop;

    public List getExamplelist() {
        System.out.println("List Element : " + examplelist);
        return examplelist;
    }

    public void setExamplelist(List examplelist) {
        examplelist = examplelist;
    }

    public Properties getExampleprop() {
        System.out.println("List Element : " + exampleprop);
        return exampleprop;
    }

    public void setExampleprop(Properties exampleprop) {
        this.exampleprop = exampleprop;
    }

}
```

And my main class is :

```
    public class CollectionExample {

    private List examplelist;

    private Properties exampleprop;

    public List getExamplelist() {
        System.out.println("List Element : " + examplelist);
        return examplelist;
    }

    public void setExamplelist(List examplelist) {
        examplelist = examplelist;
    }

    public Properties getExampleprop() {
        System.out.println("List Element : " + exampleprop);
        return exampleprop;
    }

    public void setExampleprop(Properties exampleprop) {
        this.exampleprop = exampleprop;
}

}



My .xml file is :
<bean id = "collectionExample"  class = "com.demo.spring.beans.CollectionExample" >
  <property name="examplelist">
    <list>
           <value>Credit Card</value>
           <value>COD</value>
           <value>Check</value>
           <value>Cash</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="exampleprop">
    <props>
        <prop key="one">Server Name</prop>
         <prop key="one">User Name</prop>
          <prop key="one">Password</prop>
           <prop key="one">Secure Token</prop>
    </props>
  </property>

</bean>
```

> There is a exception :  Jun 04, 2015 5:56:22 PM
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@2d8e6db6:
>   startup date [Thu Jun 04 17:56:22 IRDT 2015]; root of context
>   hierarchy Jun 04, 2015 5:56:22 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
>   loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path
>   resource [NewFile.xml] Jun 04, 2015 5:56:22 PM
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
>   refresh WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization -
>   cancelling refresh attempt
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'collectionExample' defined in class path
>   resource [NewFile.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type
>   'java.awt.List' for property 'examplelist'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.awt.List] for property
>   'examplelist': no matching editors or conversion strategy found   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     at
>   com.demo.spring.beans.CollectionExampleApp.main(CollectionExampleApp.java:9)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException:
>   Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to
>   required type 'java.awt.List' for property 'examplelist'; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of
>   type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.awt.List] for
>   property 'examplelist': no matching editors or conversion strategy
>   found     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:512)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:506)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1523)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot
>   convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type
>   [java.awt.List] for property 'examplelist': no matching editors or
>   conversion strategy found     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:287)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:461)
>     ... 17 more
>
> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'collectionExample' defined in class path
>   resource [NewFile.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type
>   'java.awt.List' for property 'examplelist'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.awt.List] for property
>   'examplelist': no matching editors or conversion strategy found   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     at
>   com.demo.spring.beans.CollectionExampleApp.main(CollectionExampleApp.java:9)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException:
>   Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to
>   required type 'java.awt.List' for property 'examplelist'; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of
>   type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.awt.List] for
>   property 'examplelist': no matching editors or conversion strategy
>   found     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:512)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:506)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1523)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot
>   convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type
>   [java.awt.List] for property 'examplelist': no matching editors or
>   conversion strategy found     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:287)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:461)
>     ... 17 more

Comment: What do you think this `Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.awt.List' for property 'examplelist'` means?

Answer (score 2):

Look closely at this part of the error message:

> Cannot convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [**java.awt.List**] for property 'examplelist'

You have imported the wrong `List` in your code. Change this:

```
import java.awt.List;
```

to this:

```
import java.util.List;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change `import java.awt.List` to `import java.util.List`.

The `java.awt.List` class is used for GUI purposes.